# How to select a row inserted before another row, timestamp?

Tags: mysql

Say I have:

```
 --------------------------------------
| Item   | value | TimeStamp           |
 --------------------------------------
| Apple  | Red   | 2013-04-15 09:34:44 |
| Orange | Orange| 2014-04-15 09:34:44 |
| Banana | Yellow| 2015-04-15 09:34:44 |
| Fruit  | Mix   | 2016-04-15 09:34:44 |
| Malon  | Red   | 2017-04-15 09:34:44 |
----------------------------------------
```

**Question:** Select just one row Inserted before a specific TimeStamp

I Tried:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE TimeStamp < '2015-04-15 09:34:44' 
 LIMIT 1 
   AND ITEM NOT NULL
```

The row I want to Select is Just the row Insert before date `2015-04-15 09:34:44` which is `2014-04-15 09:34:44`. With the above query As I used it selected all the rows inserted before date `2015-04-15 09:34:44` and I tried to limit it to 1 which the output result was `2013-04-15 09:34:44` the oldest one.

Comment: `AND ITEM NOT NULL` - This needs to be in the WHERE clause. And you need an ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `TimeStamp` < '2015-04-15 09:34:44' AND NOT `ITEM` IS NULL
ORDER BY `TimeStamp` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: It says, Unexpected error: Unexpected 'NULL' (null) what is wrong with the query?